# Block ui when keyboard is up

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've seen a couple of apps that show a transparent view on top of the current ui while the keyboard is present and if clicked it hides the keyboard. I looked around the web and couldnt find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a UIButton, custom type, the size of your screen and add it to your view when your text field (or other entry) takes focus. Make sure your edit view is brought to the front of its superview at the point you add the button (to ensure the edit view still responds to touch).

Add a target to the button which dismisses the keyboard ([myTextfield resignFirstResponder]) and removes the button.

Also make sure to remove the button when the textField dismisses normally.

Comment: Its not working, my view is a tableviewcontroller it wont show the uibutton when I run my app. Also the User is inputting text is via uisearchbar